# Show that the union $\{e_k \mid k \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{(1/k)_{k \in \mathbb N}\}$ is linearly independent on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb C)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $e_k$ be the standard unit sequence, where all elements but the $k$th one are zeroes, and the remaining element is $1$. Show that the union
\begin{equation}
\{e_k \mid k \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{(1 / k)_{k \in \mathbb N}\}
\end{equation}
is linearly independent on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb C)$,
where the sequence space
\begin{equation}
\ell^\infty(\mathbb C) = \left\{ (x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N} \in \ell(\mathbb C) \mid \sup_{k\in\mathbb N} |x_k| < \infty \right\}\,.
\end{equation}

An infinite set of vectors is said to be linearly independent, if the vectors of all its finite subspaces are linearly independent.

#### Some thoughts

Looking at the set $\{(1/k)_{k \in \mathbb N}\}$ and the standard unit sequences $e_k$ it would seem that the harmonic sequence should be expressable in therms of these unit sequences. This is because multiplying $e_k$ by $1/k$ and then summing the resulting sequences together results in the harmonic sequence.

How could I use the fact that we are operating on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb C)$ to counteract this issue?

Comment: The thing is that you would need an infinite sum to express the harmonic sequence as a linear expression of $e_i$. Linear dependence doesn't work over infinite sums.

Comment: I don;t know where you got the problem from, but the notation is appalling: the set comprehension on the right of the union looks nothing like the singleton set containing the sequence $\langle 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Assume that a **finite** linear combination of $(e_k)$ and $s=(\frac{1}{n})$ is zero. This means

$$c_1e_{k_1}+....+c_ne_{k_n}+cs=0$$
with $c$ potentially being $0$.

Look first at the "entry" $m$, where $m > k_1,.., k_n$ to deduce that $c=0$.

Next, look individually at each of the entries $k_1,...,k_n$.

Comment: The first entry $m$ of the linear combination, as in $c(1/k)_{k \in \mathbb N}$, or the $m$th entry of the harmonic sequence itself? The latter makes more sense.

Comment: @SeSodesa The entry of the linear combination. If $c_1e_{k_1}+....+c_ne_{k_n}+cs=0$ then the $m$th entry of $c_1e_{k_1}+....+c_ne_{k_n}+cs$ is zero.

Comment: The point is that once $m>k_n,$ the $m$th component of the vector sum is $c/m$ and since each component is zero, $c=0.$ And then all the other coefficients are zero because the $\{e_k\}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Right, I got it after thinking about it a little bit. I sort of forgot, that the sequences are not finite, even if we have a finite set of them.